# Concurrent Modification Exception Writing to Table Data JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm attempting to write data to `ObservableList<Packet> iplt_data = FXCollections.observableArrayList()` by calling:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> iplt_data.addAll(Start.packets.subList(lastInsertedPacket, indexAmmount)) );
```

But getting a concurrent modification exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1231)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:1091)
    at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.iterator(ArrayList.java:1087)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:99)
    at controller.Network.lambda$3(Network.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

However, if I take the function out of `Platform.runLater`, it works fine and the data is added to the table:

```
iplt_data.addAll(Start.packets.subList(lastInsertedPacket, indexAmmount));
```

I've used the same `Platform.runLater` call on other tables and it works fine, what could be the problem here?

Comment: Is `Start.packets` somehow refering to data related to `iplt_data`?

Comment: Start.packets holds the data that gets read into the table, it's an arraylist: ArrayList<Packet>

Comment: Is `Start.packets` updated concurrently?